# variable is not declared in this scope error in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void var (){
    string name;

}

int main(){
    int var();
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
    cout<<"what is your name???"<<endl;
    cin>> name;

    return 0;
}
```

I came into a problem with c++:
it says name hasn't been declared in this scope

I can't figure it out.

The reason I have 2 classes is because I am just experimenting right now and am going to add classes and objects after I figure this problem out.

Comment: I think you should reread the book

Comment: `name` is local to `var`.  It is only visible to code that is inside `var`.

Comment: You might, just might, be looking for parameters and return values, in which case, that thing about the book.

Comment: It would help to know what this code was supposed to do. Why is there a `string name;` inside `var`? What do you think that does? What is `var` supposed to be? (You are probably getting downvotes because nobody knows what help you need. Do you not understand what "variable is not declared in this scope" means? Do you think the variable is declared in that scope? Do you think for some reason it doesn't need to be? What don't you understand?)

Answer (score 1):

1. You declared function with name `var` twice. One in the global namespace.

   void var (){
   string name;

   }

and other in the block scope of function main

```
int var();
```

The both functions are not used in the program. Moreover the first function `var` has a local variable `name` that in turn is not used in the functioon.

1. In function main there is used identifier `name`

   cin>> name;

that was declared neither in the block scope of main nor in the enclosing global namespaec. So the compiler issues the error. Identifier `name` declared in the first function with name `var` is not visible outside the function.

So you need to define identifier `name` used in function main. For example

```
string name;
```

Your program could look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string var()
{
   std::cout << "what is your name??? ";

   std::string name;

   std::cin >> name;

   return name;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "hello world " << std::endl;

   std::string name = var();
   std::cout << "hello " << name << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move "string name;" into main. You dont have the variable "name" in main's scope (its a local variable of the function "var")

Answer (score 0):

Problems that I see:

1. 'string name' either needs to be declared locally inside your 'var' method, or be declared globally.
2. Your calling the method 'var' wrong (assuming your trying to call 'var' from 'main'). In C++ you call functions without a return type (void) like this: var(); If the function has a return type, you can assign a local variable with the return type like this: int x = var();
   Note: Your void var() method does not return anything, it is void, therefore you cannot assign a local variable.

You need to read up about the basics. Dont even play with classes until you have procedural understanding.
Read up about 'scope'. A local variable (name) inside your 'var' method, cannot be used anywhere else because it is declared locally - it only can be used inside the 'var' method.

Answer (score 0):

you must declare `string name` is  a global variable, or is a local variable. 
Example:

```
#include <iosream>
#include <string>
string name;
```